# Is this use of the past perfect continuous right?

Tags: past-perfect, past-vs-past-perfect

> I was tired after the test last Friday, because **I had been studying** all day long every day for a week.

Is the use of the past perfect continuous **I had been studying** in the sentence above right? He must have slept at night during the week before the test. Isn't the following sentence more natural?

> I was tired after the test last Friday, because **I studied** all day long every day for a week.

Answer (score 1):

A short interruption (such as sleep) with respect to the time used doing something (studying) does not prevent the use of present perfect continuous (PPC) or present perfect (PP).

In your example, the use of PPC is better than PP since you want to emphasize that *you had been studying **all day long***.

The use of past simple cannot convey the meaning that studying had happened before the test date.